# Change time zone of gmdate PHP function

Tags: php, sql

I am using the gmdate PHP function  to insert the current date to the database but it shows GMT time , can I change it to my time zone +3 ?

this is the code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Students
VALUES ('','" . $info[$i]['firstname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['lastname'] . "', 
        '" . $info[$i]['sex'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['major'] . "', 
        '" . $info[$i]['favorite'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['GPA'] . "',
        '". gmdate('m/d/Y g:i:s A') . "')" ;
```

Comment: `gmdate` returns *GM* time...?! You don't say! O_o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"+3" is not a "timezone". It's an *offset from UTC/GMT*, which may change throughout the year based on DST settings. A *timezone* is something like "Europe/Berlin" or "Asia/Tokyo".

Once you have decided on a real *timezone*:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date('m/d/Y g:i:s A');
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('m/d/Y g:i:s A');
```

If all you have to work with is "+3" then a) you're screwed and b) you can simply add "3 hours" to any timestamp:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo date('m/d/Y g:i:s A', strtotime("$offset hours"));

echo date('m/d/Y g:i:s A', time() + ($offset * 60 * 60));

$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify("$offset hours");
echo $date->format('m/d/Y g:i:s A');
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you should use `date()` instead. Or use the `DateTime` object for more control over timezones.

I'd highly recommend storing GMT dates and times though, and calculate it back to your own timezone when you are displaying the data.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('now');
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London')); // Change to london time.
echo $dateTime->format('m/d/Y g:i:s A');
```

You should always work with timezone names, not offsets. You are talking about an offset of +3, but I'm sure that you only live in UTC+3:00 6 months out of the year.

Comment: but how I can calculate it when you are displaying the data.just put +3 ? that will not work

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me.

You can use the timezone offset ( date("Z") ) to handle the timezone on your server

```
   $timestamp = time()+date("Z");
echo gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s",$timestamp);
```

Comment: dude. thank god I left PHP 9 years ago after posting this question